# Active Record accepts nested attributes for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes

I'm having trouble getting this to work.  I want to use nested attributes in a form, but before I do that I need to be able to build a person (administrator) from event, like so:

```
@event = Event.new
@event.administrator.build
#=> undefined method 'build' for nil:NilClass
```

---

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  #start_date, end_date, title
  has_one :administrator, :class_name => "Person" 
  has_one :account_manager, :class_name => "Person"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :administrator
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  #fname, lname, bday
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use build_administrator instead...

```
@event = Event.new
@event.build_administrator
```

This is because you have a 'has_one' association, therefore there is no association proxy created by default.